# Is deeply nested structure bad?

Tags: c

For example

```
 struct {
   struct {
     struct {
       struct {
         int a;
         int b;
       } AA;
       struct {
         char *a;
         int b;
       } BB;
     } AAA;
     int c;
    } DDD;
    char *a;
  } XX;
```

In fact, the most deepest struct has 8 nested struct.

I prefer `a.b.c.d.e` than `a.b.c_d_e`

Any pitfalls?

Comment: In what context are you talking about? Please elaborate.

Comment: Well, I would declare those inner structures separately. That way, you can declare individual instances of them. In fact, in several decades of professional embedded C programming, I have never seen such a declaration.

Comment: @Mawg I agree, as it will be less complex to use.

Comment: Are these sub-structures useful on their own in some way, or are you just doing this to make it a pain to actually access data?

Comment: This is a bit heavy on the opinion-basedness... But here is mine: I frequently use this kind of deeply nested structures, because for the purpose they are the least evil.

Comment: You tell me? `struct XX *mystruct = malloc (500 * sizeof *mystruct);` now go iterate over all `500` and allocate for all needed pointers within and fill. Still think deeply nested structure good? Use as last resort only.

Comment: I have no problem with the nesting, but I have a problem with all the structs being anonymous. Without names for the inner types, you'll have no choice but to use long sequences like `.DDD.AAA.AA.b`.  With names, you could create a pointer to use as a shortcut.

Comment: @ikegami: ...enter macros... 

Comment: Is this an actual issue with real code, or just a contrived, academic example?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Eeeek! In that case, I'm leaving:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a performance standpoint, separating in sub-structures may increase wasted space in the "parent" structure, as alignment and padding requirements will have to be evaluated singularly for each substructure instead of globally (unless the compiler can prove that there's no layout-compatible `struct` around that may be used to alias these sub-members).

Example:

```
struct Nested {
    int a;
    struct {
        int c;
        double d;
    } b;
};
```

On most common modern machines will be placed in memory like

```
0x00 a
0x04 (padding)
0x08 b.c
0x0c (padding)
0x10 b.d
Total: 0x18 bytes
```

while the equivalent "flattened" structure

```
struct Flattened {
    int a;
    int c;
    double d;
};
```

will have all its members contiguous.

```
0x00 a
0x04 c
0x08 d
Total: 0x10 bytes
```

---

This is pretty much the only performance pitfall I can think of. The most important thing to actually evaluate is the usability cost. Deeply nested sub-structures are *generally* more verbose to use, so you should reflect on *why* are you doing this and if it's actually worth it.

Are these entities that stand on their own, without the main structure? As in, your client code may want to make a copy of (or take a pointer to) one of them? Then take their definition out of your parent struct and give them a name. This is the usual case, and I see no problem to nest *instances* as much as you want - that's what actually what happens when you do OOP. Also notice that if you have pointers and stuff to be initialized in each structure you should probably provide some function to do so (in a similar way to how constructors are used in OO languages) to avoid replicating tedious code all around.

Do you need to exploit in some way the fact that are in facts structs - for example you have an array of them as a member (or, in C++, you want to exploit the automatic definition of the copy constructor for most of your members)? Then you may be OK, although again, not exporting a definite name is being evil towards your clients (what if they want a pointer to one of these objects to save some typing?).

Are you using them inside a (tagged) `union`, as "alternative active types"? That's a legitimate use case - although just for the first level!

Are you grouping stuff just for the sake of grouping? Then think twice, [you may be falling in a similar trap as what happens sometimes with (C++) namespaces](https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/letter-the-sixth-belatedly/):

> Why can we not take advantage of our patient’s mania for hierarchy? Can we not encourage them to write code like this:
>
> ```
> namespace MyLibrary {
>     namespace Useful {
>         namespace Utility {
>            int f();
>         }
>         namespace Business {
>            int f();
>            namespace Utility {
>                 int f();
>            }
>        }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It turns out that almost no encouragement is needed. Humans apparently actually like writing stuff like this:
>
> ```
> MyLibrary::Useful::Business::Utility::f();
> ```
>
> and when they have done so seem to think they have done something profound. The thought of naming the functions so that their own names are distinct seems repellent to them. And even when the names are distinct, and there is absolutely no reason to use these ludicrous constructs, they will still embrace them as they would long-lost lovers.

Over-categorizing stuff is way overrated.